# PHP Extract Line

Tags: php, registry

I need to extract "C:\Documents and Settings" from the last line of this data:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft
ExcludeSubDirs   REG_DWORD 0x1
ExtensionList  REG_SZ 
FirstAction          REG_DWORD 0x11
ThreatName          REG_SZ         C:\Documents and Settings
Owner          REG_DWORD 0x3
ProtectionTechnolog  REG_DWORD 0x1
SecondAction  REG_DWORD 0x11
DirectoryName  REG_SZ         C:\Documents and Settings
```

How can I extract "C:\Documents and Settings" or whatever the value is multiple times using PHP?

Comment: @David Lock: How are you obtaining the string? It may be delimited by newline characters, which would make things easier.

Comment: Do you have that data in a string or are you trying to pluck it directly from the registry?

Comment: Do you know the key names beforehand?

Comment: I have the data in a string. The suggestions below are not working.

Comment: The problem is that the data is not formatted in the output like above.

The actual output in View Source of the web page is like this:

DirectoryName REG_SZ C:\Docs  SOmethingElse  REG_SZ   File

Comment: @David Are you looking for a particular key (ie DirectoryName)?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to get the DirectoryName value each time it appears (the value is C:\whatever)

I need to extract whatever is between DirectoryName REG_SZ and HKEY every time it appears.

Ex (this appears about ten times):

DirectoryName    REG_SZ   C:\docs  HKEY

Comment: So whatever is between DirectoryName REG_SZ and HKEY

Comment: @David See my updated answer. I've included a working sample of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions

```
$str = 'your string';
preg_match_all('!HKEY.+?DirectoryName\s+REG_SZ\s+([^\n]+)!s', $str."\nHKEY", $matches);
$dirs = @array_map('trim', $matches[1]);
```

Your matches will be in the `$dirs` array.
Here is a working sample: http://ideone.com/rdTOx

Comment: The two asterisks are actually supposed to bold the statement.

How can I do it without the asterisks?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
$pattern = '#\*\*DirectoryName\s+REG_SZ\s+(.*?)\*\*#';
if (preg_match($pattern, $input, $output)) {
   print_r($output);
}
```

Comment: I think what you want is a positive lookbehind. This will check that Directory Name REG_SZ exists before the matched text but not return it in the match

Answer (score 0):

I found this on google.

Just put the line containing "DirectoryName" into the function.

```
preg_match('DirectoryName.*', $str, $matches);
$directory_line = $matches[0];
```

http://samburney.com/blog/regular-expression-match-windows-or-unix-path

Answer (score 0):

If this is on Windows, you can access the value directly through the COM interface:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$result = $WshShell->RegRead(
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectoryName');

echo $result; // C:\Documents and Settings
```

The above assumes there really is a key "DirectoryName" at the given position.

And there is also this class (cant tell if it's any good):

- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1426-PHP-Access-to-the-Windows-Registry.html

Comment: Right, but I need to get multiple DirectoryName, not just one.

Comment: @David not sure I understand. Just change the key.

Comment: @Gordon I think he needs to get a whole bunch of them.

Comment: @NullUser and why cant he fetch the whole bunch? :)

Comment: @Gordon I am guessing that he doesn't have list with all of them.

Comment: @NullUser well, maybe. Anyway, it's not like I'm insisting he does it with COM. Just trying to give alternatives to what was already suggested.